# Finite limits in category of finitely-presented models of equational theory

Tags: category-theory

Given an equational theory $\mathbb{T}$, it is known that the category fp-$\mathbb{T}$-mod of all finitely-presented models of $\mathbb{T}$ in $Sets$ has finite colimits. But is it known whether this category also has finite limits?

Comment: @Vladimir: nope. Try writing it down.

Comment: @Qiochu right, of course, otherwise my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930595/ about kernel pairs of finitely presented models being finitely generated would have a very easy answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not in general.  For instance, take groups.  The free group $F_2$ on two generators is finitely presented, as is the free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^2$ on two generators.  But the equalizer in groups of the canonical homomorphism $F_2\to \mathbb{Z}^2$ and the trivial homomorphism is the subgroup $[F_2,F_2]$, which is free on infinitely many generators.  If an equalizer of these maps existed in finitely presented groups, there would be a single finitely presented group $G$ with a map $\varphi:G\to [F_2,F_2]$ such that every map from a finitely presented group to $[F_2,F_2]$ factors uniquely through $\varphi$.  But this would imply $\varphi$ is surjective, since every element of $[F_2,F_2]$ can be in the image of a map from a finitely presented group (namely $\mathbb{Z}$).  Since $[F_2,F_2]$ is not finitely generated, no such $\varphi$ can exist.